# Integer value keeps resetting to zero when calling method

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to simulate an economy so what I need is for my raw material to pile up at a steady rate. I am unsure of how to proceed because whenever I use the += operators, the integer mineral doesn't stack.

```
namespace Finite_State_Machine_5
{
    class Economy
    {
        public static void Market() // static void Main simply calls Economy.Market()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This.");
            Thread.Sleep(250);

            int miningRate = 4;     // This is the rate at which the resource is mined.
                                    // If it is increased, Random() will be able to generate from a larger selection,
                                    // increasing the chances of getting a larger integer.

            int hydrogenIncome = RandomNumber.GetRandomClass(1, miningRate);    // RandomNumber.GetRandomClass (omitted) 
                                                                                // generates a random number between 1 and miningRate

            // hydrogenIncome is the integer which is continually increasing.
            // Every time AlphaCygni.Income is called, it takes the hydrogenIncome integer and adds it to int mineral.

            AlphaCygni.Income(hydrogenIncome);

            ContinueLoop();
        }

        static void ContinueLoop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("End.");

            // ContinueLoop simply keeps the loop going, calling Economy.Market() so the whole process will continue.

            Thread.Sleep(250);

            Economy.Market();
        }
    }
}

namespace Finite_State_Machine_5
{
    public class AlphaCygni : StarSystem
    {
        public static int Income(int a)
        {
            // Here with int mineral, you can see it starts at 0 but each addition with a (hydrogenIncome) should increase the number.

            int mineral = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(mineral);
            return mineral;

            // The result of the addition returns mineral
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that int "mineral" does not stack. The random int "a" gets added to "mineral" but every time the class is called, instead of int mineral getting bigger due to the += "a" operation, it just starts back to 0.

How do I tell the program to keep its value? Do I need a different operator? Do I need a different data type?

Comment: I don't see a single addition happening.

Comment: One doesn’t call a class. Also, what’s `RandomNumber`?

Comment: Also what do you mean "when I parse it (C#)" - there is not a single call to any `Parse` methods in sample...

Comment: RandomNumber is a class. It's not present in this example.

Comment: I was meaning to say that I was attempting to make the integer keep its value whenever the class' method was accessed.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it starts at `0` again, that's what you are setting it to in the `Income` method. You need `mineral` to be a static member:

```
public class AlphaCygni : StarSystem
{
    private static int mineral = 0;
    public static int Income(int a)
    {
        // Here with int mineral, you can see it starts at 0 but each addition with a (hydrogenIncome) should increase the number.

        mineral += a
        Console.WriteLine(mineral);
        return mineral;

        // The result of the addition returns mineral
    }
}
```

Or, you could try and understand object orientated programming and use instances of classes instead of a bunch of static classes with static methods and members.

Without knowing *exactly* what you are doing. I would refactor this into something like this:

```
public class StarSystem
{
    public int Minerals { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public StarSystem(string name) 
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

And now, instead of creating derived classes for every system (which will quickly become unmanageable), you can just create an instance of `StarSystem`:

```
var alphaCygni = new StarSystem("Alpha Cygni");
```

And to increase it's `Minerals` property:

```
alphaCygni.Minerals += hydrogenIncome;
```

Note that you will *not* create a new instance of `StarSystem` every time you run your `Market` method, you need to keep the references to the instances you created so you can update them.

If you have a bunch of these (which I assume you probably do), then you could but them in a collection. A dictionary might be a good fit:

```
var starSystems = new Dictionary<string,StarSystem>();

starSystems["Alpha Cygni"] = new StarSystem("Alpha Cygni");
starSystems["Sol"] = new StarSystem("Sol");
//... and so on
```

And when you want to increase their `Minerals`:

```
starSystems["Alpha Cygni"].Minerals += hydrogenIncome;
```

You might even use an `enum` for the key rather than strings to avoid mistyping the system name. Or you might create your own specialized collection derived from `Dictionary` to avoid having to type the name twice when you create a new `StarSystem` and add it to the collection.

Or if you don't need to be able to quickly access an instance of `StarSystem` by name, a simple list would be sufficient.

So your `Economy` class might become something like this:

```
public class Economy
{
    private Dictionary<string,StarSystem> systems;

    public Economy()
    {
        // Create and populate your systems
        // We'll hardcode a couple here, but you might load them some external resource
        systems = new  Dictionary<string,StarSystem>();
        starSystems["Alpha Cygni"] = new StarSystem("Alpha Cygni");
        starSystems["Sol"] = new StarSystem("Sol");
    }

    public void Market() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This.");
        Thread.Sleep(250);

        int miningRate = 4;     // This is the rate at which the resource is mined.
                                // If it is increased, Random() will be able to generate from a larger selection,
                                // increasing the chances of getting a larger integer.

        int hydrogenIncome = RandomNumber.GetRandomClass(1, miningRate);    // RandomNumber.GetRandomClass (omitted) 
                                                                            // generates a random number between 1 and miningRate

        // this will increase every system by the same amount
        // that's probably not exactly what you want, but you can adapt as needed
        foreach (var system in systems.Values)
        {
            system.Minerals += hydrogenIncome;
        }


        ContinueLoop();
    }

    private void ContinueLoop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("End.");

        // ContinueLoop simply keeps the loop going, calling Economy.Market() so the whole process will continue.

        Thread.Sleep(250);

        Market();
    }
}
```

Although I suspect that `miningRate` and/or `hydrogenEconomy` are supposed to be class members too. It's really not clear from your description.

Comment: This need to reference `a` as `hydrogenIncome` is not in scope.

Comment: Thank you. I will do so immediately.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a web page that talks about how to use instances of classes effectively? I am unsure about how to proceed.

Comment: @user255919: Pretty much any (half way decent) tutorial on C# should cover object oriented concepts. I edited my question to add a little of how I'd approach it, but not knowing all the details of what you are trying to do, it may or may not fit for you.